# Getting Blob object after posting data

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am posting some to data a rest api and should be getting a blob object as response. I need to download that blob or I would need to mail that in my angular application. But I am trying to figure out how to capture the blob object in response. My dataservice file is :

```
export class DataService<Type> {
private resolveSuffix: string = '?resolve=true';
private actionUrl: string;
private headers: Headers;

constructor(private http: Http, private httpClient:HttpClient) {    }
public issueId(asset: Type): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.httpC.post('http://localhost:3001/api/system/identities/issue', asset, {responseType: "blob"})
    .toPromise();
}
```

I am getting error :

```
property httpC doesn't exist on type 'DataService<Type>'
```

EDIT : first error fixed, now the error is
    Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Observable'

Comment: You call `toPromise` but declared the method as returning an `Observable`.. either change method's return type to `Promise<Blob>` or don't call `toPromise()`

Comment: I edited the question to show the original error, please do not solve your question by editing it, as it is confusing when other answers have already been given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now the error is Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Observable'

The error seems pretty clear. If you look at the documentation for httpClient methods, you can see that they return Observable.

The return value of your service is Observable

All you should need is to remove the `toPromise()` from your return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your constructor. You're calling it `httpC` in the signature and not `httpClient` which means your call should use `this.httpC.post` instead.

Comment: Ya I corrected that but now I am getting error: Type 'Promise<Blob>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Blob>'

Comment: like @Pac0 said in his answer, remove `toPromise()`